# Retrofit returns an empty array

Tags: android, retrofit

I can't get a grasp on Retrofit.. I have an api that returns a result like this: {"user":[{"id":"11","username":"jason95","password":"9355a70301e214efa92b0c5a75be3d29"}]}
This is my interface: http://notepad.cc/retrointerface
This is my code for the callback: http://notepad.cc/retrocallback
If anyone can point me to the correct way to Retrofit, I would GREATLY appreciate it..

Comment: Is it that you're trying to understand how conceptually retrofit works or are you have issues running your code?  If it's a code issue I would recommend some logs with an error of some sort so that we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: @MiguelLavigne I have already added logs. I don't understand how Retrofit loads the information into my object. I already made a User object and set callbacks, why doesn't it give me JSON back or load into my object? It returns an empty array, is it not finding the "user" array or am I doing something wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Retrofit uses Gson to parse and map the response body from the server to your result object. With the response you're expecting, you need to write a class that maps the JSON object to a Java object. Something like below:

```
public class ResponseObject {
   User[] user;

   class User {
      String id;
      String username;
      String password;
   }
}
```

You need to read more about Gson to get that part right. Here's a nice tutorial about using Retrofit with Gson: http://engineering.meetme.com/2014/03/best-practices-for-consuming-apis-on-android/

You could use something other than Gson, but Gson works with Retrofit without any hassle, and will probably fit your needs perfectly.

Comment: I've used GSON before, I'm just confused how Retrofit uses GSON to store the information into my object. Whats the point of a ResponseObject class, and how would I access the array to tell it how to store it in my User object? I'm a bit confused on how this library functions..

Comment: Retrofit works with Gson by default, just by specifying a Callback<ResponseObject> in your Retrofit interface, it will use Gson to convert the response from the server to that object type. The ResponseObject class acts as the Java mapping to your JSON documents. You don't need to do anything else. There's no magic here, it's actually just using [GsonConverter](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/converter/GsonConverter.html), you can code up your own converter if you wish.

Comment: You can check the official sample for Retrofit here: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-samples/github-client/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/GitHubClient.java
It may help to experiment with it a bit to better understand the library.

Comment: Seems like I'm doing everything correct, I wonder if it's my JSON response that's causing this trouble.

Comment: Does my object have to be a subclass of the Response object?

Comment: No. Response is a bit lower level if you want to do more advanced stuff or access the raw unconverted server response.

Comment: I meant Response as in ResponseObject that you created, not the Response object from the Retrofit library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58573/discussion-between-user1064249-and-hassan-ibraheem).

Comment: FINALLY GOT IT WORKING! I had to subclass my User object to the UserResponse object and create a List<User> user object instead
edit: gave you correct answer because I copied your structure and added a List instead of one object